# Java Reflection : check if object is already created

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

```
   BeanInfo componentBeanInfo = null;
   List<String> propNames =new ArrayList<String>();
   Object nestedObject=null;
            try {
            componentBeanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(sourceObject.getClass());  
            final PropertyDescriptor[] props=componentBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
            String [] parameters = getParameters(); //ObjectA.code="abc",ObjectA.type="single"
            for (String parameter : parameters) {
                boolean isNestedField = isNestedPropertyRead(parameter);
                for(PropertyDescriptor prop : props){
                    if(isNestedField){
                        String[] fullParam = parameter.split("\\.");//ObjectA.code
                        String nestedObj = fullParam[0];//ObjectA
                        String nestObjField = fullParam[1];//code
                        if(nestedObj.equalsIgnoreCase(prop.getName())){
                            Class<?> classType = Class.forName(prop.getPropertyType().getName());                       
                            BeanInfo nestedBeanInfo;
                            nestedBeanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(classType);
                                final PropertyDescriptor[] nestedProps =nestedBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
                                    for(PropertyDescriptor nestedProp : nestedProps){
                                        if(nestedProp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nestObjField)){
                                            Class<?> nestedClassType = Class.forName(nestedProp.getPropertyType().getName());
                                            Object value = convertToObject(nestedClassType,value(parameter));
                                            try {                                       
                                                /*if(isNewProperty(prop.getName(),propNames)){
                                                 nestedObject = classType.newInstance();
                                                }*/
                                                if(nestedObject == null) {
                                                nestedObject  = classType.newInstance();
                                                }
                                                nestedProp.getWriteMethod().invoke(nestedObject, value);
                                                prop.getWriteMethod().invoke(sourceObject,nestedObject );
                                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                          break;
                                        }
                                    }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(prop.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(parameter)){                    
                        try {
                            Class<?> classType = Class.forName(prop.getPropertyType().getName());
                            Object value = convertToObject(classType,value(parameter));
                            prop.getWriteMethod().invoke(sourceObject, value);
                            break;
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
      }catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

> In above code snippet I'm facing issue w.r.t following lines -

```
    nestedObject  = classType.newInstance();
```

> This creates new Instance every time and because of which i end up up
>   setting  values to new nested objects each time overriding the
>   previous object. How can i avoid this and set values to already
>   created object in loop. Can anyone please suggest how can i get it
>   working?
>
> I'll definitely be changing below piece of code also as generic one
>   rather than limiting to one instance of ' . '  as delimiter.But
>   thought of getting the looping logic right first.

```
String[] fullParam = parameter.split("\\.");//ObjectA.code
String nestedObj = fullParam[0];//ObjectA
String nestObjField = fullParam[1];//code
```

> **UPDATE-1**- @javaguy -
>   My object structure looks like below-

```
public class OuterObject {

private String field1;

private ObjectA field2;

private ObjectB field3;

private String  field4;

...// can have lot of nested objects of different types like ObjectA,ObjectB etc
```

}

public class ObjectA {

```
private String field1;

private int field2;

private String field3;

...
```

}

public class ObjectB {

```
private String field1;

private String field2;

private String field3;

...
```

}

> As per your logic, nestedObject will have instance of ObjectA when
>   ObjectA's field (say field2) is encountered first.When we get ObjectB's field next (say field1)
>   we check if nestedObject is null and since it is not null we **don't
>   create new instance for ObjectB**.Because of this we end up setting
>   ObjectB's field value (field1) in ObjectA in following line-
>   `nestedProp.getWriteMethod().invoke(nestedObject, value);` This
>   results in error - **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not
>   an instance of declaring class**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could make it work after adding following lines of code -

```
Object nestedObject = prop.getReadMethod().invoke(sourceObject);                                            
if(nestedObject == null){
        nestedObject  = classType.newInstance();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `Object nestedObject=null;` outside the loop and then create the instance only once by checking that it is `null` as shown below:

```
if(nestedObject == null) {
    nestedObject  = classType.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: I had it declared the same way outside loop.Please see my latest edit. It's not working still as it will fail if lastly iterated object's type is different from that of current object's type in following lines - nestedProp.getWriteMethod().invoke(nestedObject, value); Here 'nestedObject' will be holding type of lastly iterated object.

Comment: where is the `if` check? I couldn't find it in the your code?

Comment: I did test it with if condition you mentioned and also with similar logic (which is commented out) before that.But it was not working for the reason i mentioned in my last comment.it throws error w.r.t to type of object we are using in first parameter of invoke method.

Comment: To make it clear - it can have ObjectB ObjectC (as nested in same class along with ObjectA).in that case as per your logic it may also have ObjectB or C as lastly iterated nested object and we try to set ObjectA's field to it wrongly which results in error.